# Android New Project Problem

Tags: android

When i create a new project i am getting the following error. But the R.java file had been created.

```
[2010-12-06 09:38:18 - Hello] ERROR: Unable to open class file D:\Projects\Android\Training\Hello\gen\com\variable3\hello\R.java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting three ways to solve it .

1) Right click on your project and do "Close Project". After some time , maybe 30 sec reopen the project. This might solve the bug in eclipse.

2) Delete the project from the workspace, (Don't delete it entirely from the harddisk). And Import your project to the workspace again. It will solve the inherent bug of eclipse. (Also it would be a nice option to put your project in the current eclipse workspace)

3) Delete your eclipse and download it again , I have found Eclipse Galileo (Build id: 20090920-1017) to be good. :)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This Happens to me all the times, at first I did what Shahab was explaining, but an easier way is to right click the project, go to source, then clean up.

Answer (score 1):

In your /src folder try creating *.class using javac.
Then copy to /bin folder *.class file and then run javah command.